# Did Krishna ever talk other than the four caste system or mention specific caste name?

Tags: krishna, caste-system, varna

In this question, I am assuming the meaning of the words caste, **Varna**, class stands for same. Don't consider tribes as same as caste.

Consider the following talks by Krishna in [Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm)

From [Udyoga Parva Section 29](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05029.htm)

> Krishna said, '...Thou must, O Sanjaya, take into thy consideration **the division of the four castes** and the scheme of respective duties allotted to each. ...'

From the [Bhagavad Gita 4.13](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06028.htm)

> "The Holy One said,--'.....The **quadruple division of castes** was created by me according to the distinction of qualities and duties. ....'

Does Krishna talk about any other statement beyond this four-class system such as ***out of the caste system, 5th caste, etc.,*** anywhere in Mahabharata or in any other texts?

Comment: What do you mean by "out of the caste system" ? Its not clear.

Comment: Persons not coming under any of the four castes....

Comment: I think Brahmachari would be the one who wouldn't come under any caste.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto No.. Brahmachari certainly have a caste.. He is talking about an outcaste... who does not belong to any of the 4 castes... They are also known as mixed-caste or antyaja.. for example Chandala is an antyaja.

Comment: Your question title is out of context and brings entire teaching of krishna nothing more than caste system.. please be specific in title

Comment: @PrasannaR Oh. Thanks for suggesting. If possible please edit according to your convenience and I will monitor whether it is apt for my intention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Bhagavata Purana,

While Krishna is explaining about the way to worship govardhana hill, he mentions about outcastes.

http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/24/28

> After giving the appropriate food to everyone else, including such
>   fallen souls as dogs and dog-eaters, you should give grass to the cows
>   and then present your respectful offerings to Govardhana Hill.

The sanskrit word used in the verse is candala which is an outcaste. Some translate it as outcaste.

http://srimadbhagavatam.org/canto10/chapter24.html

'To act appropriately in respect of everyone, also should be thought of others: fallen souls like dogs and outcasts. After next having given grass to the cows the offerings should be presented to the mountain'

If dog-eater and outcasts are synonymous in the way they are used in scriptures,
then even in Bhagavad Gita 5.18 we find Krishna talks about outcasts.

vidyä-vinaya-sampanne
brähmaëe gavi hastini
suni caiva **sva-päke** ca
paëòitäù sama-darçinaù

Comment: Anywhere did he mention that the people from the given 4 classes won't eat dog?

Comment: The exact sanskrit word used is candala which is definitely an outcaste. It was translated as dog eater. Some translate it as outcaste.

Comment: Refer http://srimadbhagavatam.org/canto10/chapter24.html

Comment: @hanugm  A Chandala is also referred to as a "Svapaka" which means "one who cooks/eats dog meat".